# filetype and corresponding program that will honor control characters

Tags: node.js, logging, tail, control-characters

I am using Node.js to write to log files, using the `colors` module which I believe inserts control characters into strings, for coloring/text formatting which will display in a terminal application.

When I write to the terminal directly, it shows colors, but when I write to a .log file and then tail the log file with either `Terminal.app` or `iterm2`, it does not show colors/text formatting. Does anybody know why this is? My guess is that when you write to the log file the control characters don't get saved? In that way, when tailing they won't display at all?

Perhaps if I write to .txt file or some other type of file, the control characters will remain?

How does this work exactly? At some point the control characters are getting stripped or ignored and I am not sure how or when.

Answer (score 1):

See [this code](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/dfb15b55382772ba4fd34fc21922a2d83e9d34d3/lib/system/supports-colors.js#L40-L42).

It checks if the output is going to a terminal (by checking [`process.stdout.isTTY`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)) or to somewhere else, like a file. If the latter, no color codes are outputted.

Comment: thanks, makes sense, do you happen to know if the tail command can handle control characters? Or is always going to show plain text, wondering which programs interpret the control chars and which don't...

Comment: I was looking through here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196118/prevent-tail-from-modifying-the-charset-of-the-terminal

Comment: you're absolutely right, I changed that boolean and it puts the control characters into the .log file, if I view the log file with a non-terminal app, we can see the control chars, but when viewing with a terminal app and using "tail -f" the chars are interpreted and we don't see them, seems a little crazy - what if the control chars actually meant something behind color-coding?

Comment: @AlexMills generally, you don't log control-characters as-is anyway, precisely because of what you're suggesting. That's also why `colors` doesn't output them when its output is being written to a file. The link you post suggests some good workarounds if control characters _do_ end up in your logfiles (`tail -f ... | cat -v` is an easy one).